# how to search for a filename in a list of files

Tags: java, list, file

I need to find a file name from the list of filenames and to initiate two methods according to the found result. I tried:

```
FileList result = service.files().list()
             .setPageSize(10)
             .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
             .execute();
        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
        if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No files found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Files:");
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
                Boolean found = files.contains("XYZ");
                if(found)
                {
                    insertIntoFolder();
                } else {
                    createFolder();
                }
            }
        }
```

I need to find `XYZ` (the filename) from a list of file names (like `sjh, jsdhf, XYZ, ASDF`). Once I've found it I need to stop the search. If the name doesn't match the list of names I need to create a folder only once after checking all names from that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Boolean found = files.contains("XYZ");
```

This line is problematic. `files` is a list of `File` objects, none of which will match the `String` `"XYX"`. [`List.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) essentially calls `Object.equals()` on every element of the list, and [`File.equals("XYZ")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) will always return `false`.

If you're programming in an IDE like Eclipse it should show a warning on this line, since it's a bug that can be detected at compile-time.

To determine if a `File` in a `List<File>` has a filename matching a given string you need to operate on the filename itself, so the above line should instead be:

```
boolean found = file.getName().equals("XYZ");
```

Depending on what exactly you're trying to match you might want to use `.getName()`, `.getAbsolutePath()`, or `.toString()`.

---

It's also a good idea to use the [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) API introduced in Java 7, rather than `File`, which is essentially a legacy class at this point.

If you want a more elegant solution than manually looping over files looking for a match you can use [`Files.newDirectoryStream(Path, Filter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.DirectoryStream.Filter-) which allows you to define a `Filter` predicate that only matches certain files, e.g.

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(myDirectory, p -> p.getFileName().toString().equals("XYZ"))
```

[`File.list(FilenameFilter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list-java.io.FilenameFilter-) is a similar feature for working with `File` objects, but again, prefer to use the `Path` API if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example:

```
/**
* return true if file is in filesList else return false
*/
static boolean isFileInList(File file, List<File> filesList) {
    for(File f: filesList) {
        if (f.equals(file)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<File> files;// the filelist; make sure assign these two variable.
    File file; // the file you want to test.
    if (isFileInList(file, files)) {
        //file is presented
    } else {
        //file is not presented
        createFolder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you verymuch

Answer (score -1):

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DirectoryContents {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File f = new File("."); // current directory

    FilenameFilter textFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            String lowercaseName = name.toLowerCase();
            if (lowercaseName.endsWith(".txt")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };

    File[] files = f.listFiles(textFilter);
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.print("directory:");
        } else {
            System.out.print("     file:");
        }
        System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
    }

}

}
```

Comment: How does this in any way answer the question? You offer no explanation or guidance, and this code is essentially unrelated to what OP is asking about. "*I need to find XYZ (fileName) from list of file names (like sjh, jsdhf, XYZ, ASDF). Once I've found it I need to stop the search*. Explaining how to use a `FilenameFilter` would be a reasonable answer, but this is just a block of code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer